# Eclipse says a TableRow is useless but I can't find a better way

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm working on an Android app, and I'm wondering whether I can do something differently and/or better in order to avoid warnings from Eclipse.  For clarity, I'll include the XML layout in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#262626"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#262626"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5.0dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/title_rcon_console"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20.0sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rcon_console"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/command_table"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="5.0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="9.0sp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sending"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rcon_console"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#262626"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5.0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10.0dp"
        android:paddingRight="10.0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dp"
        android:text="@string/msg_rcon_sending"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14.0sp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/command_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#262626"
        android:paddingBottom="5.0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dp"
        android:stretchColumns="0" >

        <TableRow>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/field_command"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="14.0sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="@string/button_send" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is with the `TableLayout` and `TableRow` elements.  Eclipse is showing the following warning for the `TableRow`:

> This TableRow layout or its TableLayout parent is useless; transfer
>   the background attribute to the other view

I'm using the `TableLayout` because it's the only way I could find to align the `EditText` and `Button` side-by-side, and have the `EditText` span the entire space not occupied by the `Button`.  The end result looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

So, is Eclipse correct in saying that one or both of the table elements are useless?  Can I do this a different or more proper way, and have the same result?  Or is this just a spurious warning which doesn't apply here and can be ignored?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `is Eclipse correct...` **Definetely**. Useless layouts and views are bad for performances. You can rethink your layout by aligning these elements to the parent's bottom, and corners (start with the button, add the EditText), then place all other Views. A RelativeLayout is very useful for this kind of optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you did this?

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/command_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#262626"
    android:paddingBottom="5.0dp"
    android:paddingTop="5.0dp"
     >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/field_command"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send_button"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="14.0sp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Another nice quirk about this apporoach is that irrespective of the content you place on your screen,this EditText and Button combination will always remain exactly above the soft keyboard.If you want to avoid that,then ir requires a little bit more work

Comment: Thanks @Droidekas, this worked perfectly with a few minor changes.  I had to change the `layout_height` of the `Button` and `EditText` to be `wrap_content` or else these elements filled the entire screen vertically.  I also removed the `android:stretchColumns="0"` from the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @Dave sorry i answered this on my phone :)..shall make the edits as you mentioned